# SQL - Adding a blank row

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, sql-server-2014

I'm dealing with software that will use the query I'm building to get data from the database. The problem is that the software doesn't have tools to determine the table size, so I need to add a blank row after the last row of data, so the software can recognize the end of the table.
Here's an example of what the query would give:

[image]

And here's an example of what I need to get from the query:

[image]

I know it would be better to solve it in the application, but in this case I need to change my query. Is it possible?

Edit: I'm using SQL Server 2014, the database name is Test and the table name is Table2.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` after your query to add the blank row:

```
select t.* from (
  select FieldA, FieldB
  from Table2
  ..........
  union all
  select null, null 
) t
order by case when coalesce(t.FieldA, t.FieldB) is null then 1 else 0 end
```

or:

```
select t.FieldA, t.FieldB from (
  select 0 as isblankrow, FieldA, FieldB
  from Table2
  ..........
  union all
  select 1, null, null 
) t
order by isblankrow
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is:

```
select t.*
from t
union all
select t.*
from (select 1 as x) x left join
     t
     on 1 = 0   -- always fails
order by (case when fieldA is not null then 1 else 2 end)
```

This returns one additional row with all columns being `NULL`.

Note:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so you need an `order by`.  The above assumes that the first column is never `NULL`.

Comment: @DanielGutierres . . . Is there a reason you didn't accept this answer?  Besides being first, it is the only one where you don't need to list out the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I have full solution available on dbfiddle for SQL Server 2014. 
[dbfiddlelink](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8b9e23f9ea4a0c5beedd5fae3463554c)

The query should be,

```
Select * 
from (select FieldA,FieldB 
      from Table2 
      union
      select null,null) tab 
 order by FieldA Desc
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I didn't know about dbfiddle either, thank you for the knowledge!